# Changing column value in groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to change values of a column in 2 groups like country column has several value but I need US and Non -US in Pandas Dataframe. Please suggest how to achieve this in python dataframe.

I tried below code but no luck

1.

```
if df['Country'] != 'United-States':
     df['Country'] = 'Non-US'
```

2.

```
df.loc[df['Country'] != 'United-States', 'Country'] = 'Non-US'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['United-States', 'Canada', 'Slovakia']})
print(df)
         Country
0  United-States
1         Canada
2       Slovakia

df['Country'] = np.where(df['Country'] == 'United-States', 'US', 'Non-US')
```

Or:

```
df['Country'] = np.where(df['Country'] != 'United-States', 'Non-US', 'US')
```

Another solution:

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].map({'United-States':'US'}).fillna('Non-US')

print (df)
  Country
0      US
1  Non-US
2  Non-US
```

Comment: I like this solution best. The latter being a nice one liner. @OP you should take a look at this one

Comment: df['Country'] = np.where(df['Country'] != 'United-States', 'Non-US', 'US')                     
I tried above one but it is updating all as Non-US

Comment: @chetansharma - I think there should be problem with some whitespaces? Can you check it by  `print (df['Country'].tolist())`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
US = df[df['Country']=='United-States']
Other = df[df['Country']!='United-States']
```

This will surely help

Comment: `I need to change values of a column in 2 groups like country column has several value but I need US and Non -US in Pandas Dataframe` what OP - so your solution is clearly wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply function as below:

```
df['country']=df['country'].apply(lambda x: "Non-US" if x != 'United-States' else "United-States")
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the NumPy version in @jezrael's answer, pandas also has its own `Series.where()` function:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['United-States', 'Canada', 'Slovakia']})

>>> df.Country.where(df.Country == 'United-States', 'Non-US')
0    United-States
1           Non-US
2           Non-US
```

> The where method is an application of the if-then idiom. For each
>   element in the calling DataFrame, if cond is True the element is used;
>   otherwise the corresponding element from the DataFrame other is used.
>
> The signature for DataFrame.where() differs from numpy.where().
>   Roughly df1.where(m, df2) is equivalent to np.where(m, df1, df2).